# SilverStripe static error page

Tags: silverstripe

Is it possible to set a static 404 error page **without the need to create this page in the CMS SiteTree**?

I tried setting an *ErrorPage.ss* in the *Layout* folder with the error text in there. It only works when the error page is created in the SiteTree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 404 error page in the site tree outputs the page html to `/assets/error-404.html` for use in the case the site tree 404 page is not found.

In our main `.htaccess` should be the following line that sets where the server should look for the static 404 error page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
```

If we unpublish our 404 error page in the site tree the server will use this static html page. We can then edit the `/assets/error-404.html` file to control the static 404 error page.